# How to Highlite clicked/selected grid in Grid View

Tags: java, android, xml, android-glide

I'm using a grid view to show images using Glide. How can I highlite a selected image in the grid? Also I need to restrict the user to select only one image, If user clicks one more image, first image should be deselected.

Here is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/galleryGridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnWidth="280dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/selected_grid">
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and Java code

```
GridView gallery = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.galleryGridView);

        gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                    int position, long arg3) {

                       // Help me here

            }
        });
    }
```

Adapter

```
private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        /** The context. */
        private Activity context;

        /**
         * Instantiates a new image adapter.
         *
         * @param localContext
         *            the local context
         */
        public ImageAdapter(Activity localContext) {
            context = localContext;
            images = getAllShownImagesPath(context);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return images.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                            ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                picturesView = new ImageView(context);
                picturesView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                picturesView
                        .setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(270, 270));

            } else {
                picturesView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            Glide.with(context).load(images.get(position))
                    .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).centerCrop()
                    .into(picturesView);

            return picturesView;
        }
```

Comment: add your code of ImageAdapter

Comment: you can handle it inside adapter

Comment: @Pravin ImageAdapter added.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage by something like this

```
 gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                int position, long arg3) {


         for(int i = 0; i < arg0.getChildCount(); i++)
         {
            if(i == position)
              arg0.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            else
              arg0.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

         }

        }
    });
```

or 2nd way just make a simple selector for gridview
`list_selector.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/yourcolor" />
  <item android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

and set listSelector of your gridview like

`android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"`

Comment: what was the issue.?

Comment: they did nothing. It is not highlighting anything. Color is getting behind the image so it is not visible. For gif images, I can see the color applied.

Comment: i think you use only `ImageView` on your adapter,that why you need to appy some padding to Your View and than after try to set background

Comment: applying padding too didn't helped

Comment: please update code for you set padding & what was the problem ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113518/discussion-between-abhishek-patel-and-ramesh).